# What location is a Cron called from?

Tags: php, json, file-io, cron

I have created a simple PHP script that is executed by a CRON daemon on my remote webserver. Every few minutes, the script looks up some JSON data on another website, and stores the results in a file in the same folder as itself.

However, it seems that the file that is used when navigating to the page in the browser, a different file is used than when the cron is executed.

In other words: When going here:

`www.example.com/cronscripts/my_script.php` the file `/home/user_xxx/domains/example.com/public_html/cronscripts/datafile.json` is used.

However, when calling the script using the following cron statement:

`/usr/local/bin/php /home/user_xxx/domains/example.com/public_html/cronscripts/my_script.php`
a file on a different location is used. Is this file in the /usr/local/bin/php folder in the Linux server? If so, I can't access it by hand because I can only access the /home/user_xxx/ folder.

Could someone tell me where the file ends up when using Cronjobs?

Comment: If you always use absolute pathnames in your script, this problem will be avoided. You can use `realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/..')`, substituting as many `..` as you need to get to the "root" of your project, and then add a path from there.

Comment: @ansh0l, I'll try it out tomorrow, when I'm working again. Don't worry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a path mismatch for the location, you are most probably using a relative path somewhere for the `json` file.

I think you should schedule your cronjob as following and see if that works

```
* * * * * cd /home/user_xxx/domains/example.com/public_html/cronscripts && /usr/local/bin/php my_script.php
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the absolute path to your script on the server i.e. /var/www/script.php

Try to use instead

*/1 * * * * php /home/user_xxx/domains/example.com/public_html/cronscripts/my_script.php

Comment: In the cron statement, I am using an absolute path. Or is that not what you mean?

Comment: can you copy and paste the syntax which from your cron?

Comment: `*/1 * * * * /usr/local/bin/php /home/user_xxx/domains/example.com/public_html/cronscripts/my_script.php` is the syntax I use for the cron.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`chdir()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chdir.php) to ensure you are starting in the proper directory may also help.

Answer (score -1):

Just a side note: please *always* use #!/bin/env php
(see http://seancoates.com/blogs/use-env for more info)